# Max crop area for a given image and aspect ratio

Tags: php, gd, php-gd

Is there any PHP/GD function that can calculate this:

> Input: image width, image height and an aspect ratio to honor. Output:
>   the width/height of the **max centered** crop that **respects** the given aspect ratio
>   (despite image original aspect ratio).

Example: image is 1000x500, a.r. is 1.25: max crop is 625x500. image is 100x110, max crop is: 80x110.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no function that calculates this because it's elementary math:

```
$imageWidth = 1000;
$imageHeight = 500;
$ar = 1.25;

if ($ar < 1) { // "tall" crop
    $cropWidth = min($imageHeight * $ar, $imageWidth);
    $cropHeight = $cropWidth / $ar;
}
else { // "wide" or square crop
    $cropHeight = min($imageWidth / $ar, $imageHeight);
    $cropWidth = $cropHeight * $ar;
}
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/rWau5a)**.

Comment: Thanks. I've spent a couple of minutes and arrived to something like your code (but your solution is more elegant). Yeah, elementary but yet useful.

Comment: Very nice solution. Even though my brain completely blanks out when i try to understand it, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

As an extension to [**@Jon**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50079/jon)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8541496/3679900), here's an implementation of this approach in [PHP-GD library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)

```
/**
 * Crops image by taking largest area rectangle from center of image so that the desired aspect ratio is realized.
 * @param resource $src_image image resource to be cropped
 * @param float $required_aspect_ratio Desired aspect ratio to be achieved via cropping
 * @return resource cropped image
 */
public function withCenterCrop($src_image, float $required_aspect_ratio) {
    $crr_width = imagesx($src_image);
    $crr_height = imagesy($src_image);
    $crr_aspect_ratio = $crr_width / $crr_height;

    $cropped_image = null;
    if ($crr_aspect_ratio < $required_aspect_ratio) {
        // current image is 'taller' (than what we need), it must be trimmed off from top & bottom
        $new_width = $crr_width;
        $new_height = $new_width / $required_aspect_ratio;
        // calculate the value of 'y' so that central portion of image is cropped
        $crop_y = (int) (($crr_height - $new_height) / 2);
        $cropped_image = imagecrop(
            $src_image,
            ['x' => 0, 'y' => $crop_y, 'width' => $new_width, 'height' => $new_height]
        );
    } else {
        // current image is 'wider' (than what we need), it must be trimmed off from sides
        $new_height = $crr_height;
        $new_width = $new_height * $required_aspect_ratio;
        // calculate the value of 'x' so that central portion of image is cropped
        $crop_x = (int) (($crr_width - $new_width) / 2);
        $cropped_image = imagecrop(
            $src_image,
            ['x' => $crop_x, 'y' => 0, 'width' => $new_width, 'height' => $new_height]
        );
    }

    return $cropped_image;
}
```